# Annotate screenshots with LibreOffice Draw

Tags: libreoffice, screenshot, annotations, libreoffice-draw

I need to annotate screenshots with a Linux/Windows cross platform application.
Taking screenshots can be easily done with OS utilities and, after a while, I realised  the best way to annotate screenshots is LibreOffice Draw.

The only annoyance is that the when opening a PNG, it is adapted to the page proportions. 
I would like to adapt the page the to the PNG instead, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Like, you have (always) the same size of your PNGs?

Set up a file template with the special page size.
Same size - problem solved (isn't it?)

Comment: Take  any generic [tutorial](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/GIMP_Quickies), you'll see the proportions change.